# Border not using the correct image height

Tags: html, css, grid, border

I want to add a border to an author's picture in an author box, like the image below.

[image: Expected result]

However, the result is as follows.

[image: Actual result]

Instead of 72x72, the border is created as if the profile picture is 72x24. See below.

[image: Profile picture size according to inspector]

What's going wrong here?

Here's my code.

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 32px;
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 24px;
  grid-column-gap: 24px;
}

#author {
  background: #ffffff;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 72px 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 96px rgba(247, 237, 226, 0.24);
}

.authorPhoto {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.profilePicture {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
}
```

```html
<style></style>

<div class="block" id="author">
  <div class="authorPhoto">
    <img src="#" class="profilePicture"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>#</h2>
    <p>#</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this CSS to `.authorPhoto` and did not see any problem:

```css
border-radius: 100%;
border: 5px solid orange;
overflow: hidden;
```

### Demo

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 32px;
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 24px;
  grid-column-gap: 24px;
}

#author {
  background: #ffffff;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 72px 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 96px rgba(247, 237, 226, 0.24);
}

.authorPhoto {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  vertical-align: top;
  
  /* ADDED */
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.profilePicture {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
}
```

```html
<style></style>

<div class="block" id="author">
  <div class="authorPhoto">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/1db333/f01616" class="profilePicture"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>#</h2>
    <p>#</p>
  </div>
</div>
```